# Google Pay Push Provisioning Sample

Tags: android-pay, google-pay

I am trying to develop a routine to add a debit card from my app to Google Pay by clicking an **Add to Google Pay** button.

The Google Pay Push Provisioning documentation provides a *Little Bear* example, which I'm able to build and run. However, whenever I try to add any of the sample cards to Google Pay, it keeps throwing the following error:

***NO OPC SET - You need to set an OPC in the Settings page before you can test Push Provisioning.***

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Same here. And if you go to the settings page, the app crashes every time

Comment: Hi - I am just starting on this road and find information hard to come by.
Could you please post add a link to the Google Pay Provisioning docs and example...Please.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of the app, you can set/update the OPC on the Settings tab of the Little Bear sample app (about half way down).

[image]

Assuming you have access to the Google Pay Push Provisioning developer site, you can reach out to the Push Provisioning API support team should you need additional assistance by following the instructions at: https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/support/get-help#general_questions

Comment: Thank you, @Soc. I'll give it a try.